# How to order WP_Query with multiple posts by multiple ordering parameters?

Tags: wordpress

Does anyone know if it is possible to order a wordpress loop with multiple post types, but have each post type be ordered differently?

Say I have blog posts and events. Events have a start date and they should be in ascending order. The blog posts should be in descending order.

Suppose we're using `pre_get_posts` to try to filter this for the page loop.

You can specify anything you would use in a new WP_Query request, so we can set things like...

```
$query->set('post_type', array('posts', 'events'));
```

That much is working.

But as far as I know, there's no way to specify how to order an individual post type. Just the collection as a whole...

```
$query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
$query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
```

And I can't run a meta query on all results because only events have the start_date field populated...

So is it possible to do this within this hook?

I know how to do it by using multiple wp_query requests and merging the results, or by writing a manual query with $wpdb. I was just curious if you could do this with only the pre_get_posts hook.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/278337/wp-query-order-by-multiple-meta-keys-fields

Comment: @shamimkhan - I had high hopes for that one but it didn't work. I was not aware of named queries though so good call. It was worth a shot.